# Voting attack simply based on intentionally helpful comment

Tags: discussion, comments

I recently came across [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617690/find-sum-of-first-1000-prime-numbers-in-python#comment47380282_29617690) that had a couple of answers on it. One had 0 votes, and another had -1 votes. The question with -1 votes (the answer), seemed to simply be a link question (which I found kind of strange from a high rep user). He edited his answer to include a code example, and then again to include a one sentence description. He asked why there was a downvote, as to which I commented (something like this):

> Perhaps the down vote was on your earlier revision, to when it was a link only answer.

A few moments later, I found my reputation going down, and saw that many of my questions and answers in other various tags were being down voted, for no reason at all. His answer was deleted when I came back to the post (after looking intensely through my browser history).

I understand that serial downvoting is unacceptable by the community, but I want to know if I triggered something that prompted the answerer's behaviour. Could I have done something differently? What should the community do to learn from this?

[image: The downvotes]

Comment: Your comment was not so nicely worded. Your actual comment was **"Probably because you just made an edit, which completely changed your answer from link to code... Think before you post!"**

Comment: Perhaps, now that I think about it, it wasn't so nicely worded. (The *Think before you post!* part was where it went overboard I'm guessing). To you user, sorry... :( I guessing my wording wasn't like what I was thinking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That happens when you are *that* confrontational in comments.  Nobody likes to be told that they are incapable of thinking.  Or that there would be something wrong about improving a post by editing it.  They are nonsensical accusations that only enrage the recipient.  What happens next tends to be predictable.

There is no obligation to explain downvotes, I strongly recommend that you stop helping.  And observe the SE Primary Directive: be nice.  Everybody will be nice in return.

Comment: Why do you say that I should stop helping? Is there some extra meaning to that which I am not getting?

Comment: Not that I can think of.  You put "intentionally helpful comment" in your question title.  It was completely unhelpful.

Comment: @Zizouz212: Anyway, if it isn't reversed within two days, you might flag for help... aside from that, being reasonably polite is really always a good idea.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sure. I'll do that. :)

Comment: Neither terse comments nor retributive downvotes just "happen" as immutable laws. This whole site is about steering behaviour, and (_at least_ as much as overly direct comments), that sort of downvoting is obviously wrong, as it degrades the quality of the site's main purpose: answers. It's weird to not even acknowledge that.

Comment: @RobertGrant: I'm not sure where you get that terseness is bad...

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm referring to the comment that's...the subject of this answer? That comment. That people are saying wasn't pleasantly worded. But anyway, that's a distraction from what I was trying to say about downvotes.

Comment: @RobertGrant what do you mean?

Comment: @Zizouz212 I'm happy to answer any specific questions you have about whatever is unclear; I tried to explain what I meant the first time :)

Comment: @Deduplicator My flag got declined... After two 2 and a half weeks. :/